# ¿Como extraer de una columna de dataframe con valores tipo diccionario otras columnas segun su key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

En mi dataframe quiero extraer los valores de la columna 'name' en otras 2 columnas, una como columna de forename y otra como columna surname, si fuese un texto plano seria aplicar split y quizas ya lo tendría pero el problema aquí es que los valores de la columna 'name' estan como diccionario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'name': ({'forename': 'Lewis', 'surname':'Hamilton'},
                            {'forename': 'Nick', 'surname': 'Heidfeld'},
                            {'forename': 'Nico', 'surname': 'Rosberg'},
                            {'forename': 'Fernando','surname':'Alonso'})})
```

He estado intentando hacer esto, pero se que no es fatible:

```
data_drivers['Nombre'] = data_drivers['Nombres'].str.split(' ').str[0]
data_drivers['Apellido'] = data_drivers['Nombres'].str.split(' ').str[1]

AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor edita tu pregunta e incluye algunas filas de tu `dataframe` y el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Si tus datos vienen tal como están en tu pregunta, a través de un diccionario en tu código entonces puedes utilizar directamente `apply(pd.Series)`.

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ({'forename': 'Lewis', 'surname':'Hamilton'},
                            {'forename': 'Nick', 'surname': 'Heidfeld'},
                            {'forename': 'Nico', 'surname': 'Rosberg'},
                            {'forename': 'Fernando','surname':'Alonso'})})

df = df['name'].apply(pd.Series)
print(df)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
   forename   surname
0     Lewis  Hamilton
1      Nick  Heidfeld
2      Nico   Rosberg
3  Fernando    Alonso
```

Pero si tus datos provienen de algun archivo, digamos `csv` primero hay que asegurarnos de convertir el `string` a diccionario antes de utilizar `apply(pd.Series)`.

Ejemplo con unos datos genéricos desde un archivo "sample2.csv"

El primer punto es que el separador del diccionario es la coma (`,`) así que hay que configurar otro separador para el `csv` que podría ser punty y coma (`;`) y utilizamos `literal_eval` de la librería [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) para convertir las celdas a un diccionario

Los datos genéricos son los siguientes:

```
                                name
0  {'forename': 'A', 'surname': 'B'}
1  {'forename': 'C', 'surname': 'D'}
2  {'forename': 'E', 'surname': 'F'}
3  {'forename': 'G', 'surname': 'H'}
4  {'forename': 'I', 'surname': 'J'}
5  {'forename': 'K', 'surname': 'L'}
6  {'forename': 'M', 'surname': 'N'}
```

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv', converters={'name': literal_eval}, sep=';')
df = df['name'].apply(pd.Series)
print(df)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
  forename surname
0        A       B
1        C       D
2        E       F
3        G       H
4        I       J
5        K       L
6        M       N
```

En ambos casos si desearas conservar la columna `name` y únicamente agregar las columnas `forename` y `surname` podrías utilizar `concat` con `axis = 1` para concatenar columnas y no filas.

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv', converters={'name': literal_eval}, sep=';')
df = pd.concat([df, df['name'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
                                name forename surname
0  {'forename': 'A', 'surname': 'B'}        A       B
1  {'forename': 'C', 'surname': 'D'}        C       D
2  {'forename': 'E', 'surname': 'F'}        E       F
3  {'forename': 'G', 'surname': 'H'}        G       H
4  {'forename': 'I', 'surname': 'J'}        I       J
5  {'forename': 'K', 'surname': 'L'}        K       L
6  {'forename': 'M', 'surname': 'N'}        M       N
```

Comment: Muchas gracias... de hecho mi archivo fuente es un json, pero ya con esto de fondo quedó!!!